# Dell Vostro 3568 - wifi very slow internet connection

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have tired several things but still I cannot figure it out what can I do with my slow wifi connection. For me its like 1-4 Mb/s but on second laptop is 60-80 Mb/s. Distro version is 16.04

Here are my networking data https://paste.ubuntu.com/26518624/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help someone, my issue is resolved by

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```